# Frontespizio package: how to set names height

Tags: vertical-spacing, frontespizio

I'm writing my master's thesis and I'm having troubles with frontespizio package, since it puts names at a default height that I don't know how to change. I would like to be able to move the names at the bottom of the page as in the image

[image]

In the following the default [name]-frn.tex file that gets created

```
\documentclass [titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage [a4paper,left=1cm,bottom=1.5cm,right=1cm,top=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage {graphicx}
\usepackage [svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[nowrite,infront,standard]{frontespizio}
\nofiles 
\fontoptionnormal 
\Margini {2.25cm}{2.25cm}{2.25cm}{2.25cm}
\Universita {}
\Dipartimento {}
\Corso {}
\Titolo {}
\NCandidato {Tesi di laurea di}
\Candidato {A}
\Relatore {A}
\Correlatore {A}
\Piede {}
\begin {document}
\preparefrontpagestandard
\end {document}
```

I read package documentation and I also tried to use the command `\vspace` inside the arguments `\Candidato`, `\Relatore` etc... but didn't work.

How can I do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part related to candidate and advisors is set in a box of fixed height, precisely `0.3\textheight`.

You can remove this with a devious trick.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{frontespizio}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontespizio}

\begin{Preambolo*}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\preparefrontpagestandard}{to .3\textheight}{}{}{}
\end{Preambolo*}

\Margini {2.25cm}{2.25cm}{2.25cm}{2.25cm}
\Universita {}
\Dipartimento {}
\Corso {}
\Titolo {}
\NCandidato {Tesi di laurea di}
\Candidato {A}
\Relatore {A}
\Correlatore {A}
\Piede {}

\end{frontespizio}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I noticed that changing for example to '.2\textheight' does anything, and this I suppose because of the fixed .3 height you cited. How can I set the height in which to put the box? Edit: I solved using '\vspace' command inside '\Candidato' and '\Titolo'. Thank you very much!